# How should I structure these raster inputs for my CNN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, python-imaging-library, raster

I am following [this guide from pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/) to make a CNN which takes images and numeric data and make a single output. On the image side, this guide offers four colored images per sample, then loads, resizes, and stacks them in a montage as follows:

```py
import cv2

inputImages = []
outputImage = np.zeros((64, 64, 3), dtype="uint8")

# loop over the input image paths
    for inputImage in imagePaths:
    # load the input image, resize it to be 32 32, and then
    # update the list of input images
    image = cv2.imread(inputImage)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32))
    inputImages.append(image)

# tile the four input images in the output image such the first
# image goes in the top-right corner, the second image in the
# top-left corner, the third image in the bottom-right corner,
# and the final image in the bottom-left corner
outputImage[0:32, 0:32] = inputImages[0]
outputImage[0:32, 32:64] = inputImages[1]
outputImage[32:64, 32:64] = inputImages[2]
outputImage[32:64, 0:32] = inputImages[3]
```

The result is a montage is 4 colored images side by side like this:
[image: image montage]

My images are rasters and as such only have a single layers each. My four images represent different indices of the same place in an aerial shot, so I would have them stack on top of each other rather than side by side.
In the line:

```
outputImage = np.zeros((64, 64, 3), dtype="uint8")
```

I presume the dimension `3` refers to the RGB element of the original images.
To make my own montage I reduced this to just `np.zeros((64, 64), dtype="uint8)` but my resulting `outputImage` wasn't an image montage as suggested, but instead just a 64X64 array of numbers.

To load my rasters I am using Pillow and my code currently looks as follows:

```py
from PIL import Image

inputImages = []
outputImage = np.zeros((64, 64), dtype = 'uint8')

# relevant images
for inputMap in relevantMaps:
    mapPath = os.path.sep.join([zonePath, inputMap])
    # load input image, resize it to be 32 32, the update the input image list
    image = Image.open(mapPath)
    image = image.resize((32, 32))
    inputImages.append(image)

# tile the four input images in the output image such that:
# first image -> top left, second image -> top right
# third image -> bottom left, fourth image -> bottom right
outputImage[0:32, 0:32] = inputImages[0]
outputImage[32:64, 0:32] = inputImages[1]
outputImage[0:32, 32:64] = inputImages[2]
outputImage[32:64, 32:64] = inputImages[3]
```

My `outputImage` looks like this:

```py
array([[123, 125, 131, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [120, 125, 127, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [123, 127, 126, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       ...,
       [205, 153,  55, ..., 242, 242, 242],
       [  4, 241,  28, ..., 242, 242, 242],
       [243,  90, 211, ..., 242, 242, 242]], dtype=uint8)
```

Rather than an image montage.

I face two problems:

1. I'm not sure if I should stack my images next to each other like in the example, or on top of each other, as they are different layers of the same exact area.
2. I am not sure how to stack the images and have them remain as images, my method turns them into matrices.

I expect to get a usable image montage that I could then plop into a CNN as input.